# Django POST data in request.body but can not store in variable

Tags: python, django

I am posting some raw JSON to my backend

```
{
    "access_token": "hU5C7so4reJOYTzPyhKPs8PWq07tb",
    "id": 3,
    "order_details": [{"meal_id": 1, "quantity": 3}, {"meal_id": 2, "quantity": 2}]
}
```

However when I try to

```
print (request.POST.get("access_token"))
```

I receive `None`

But, when I do

```
print (request.body)
```

The values seem to there:

`b'{\n\t"access_token": "hU5C7so4reJOYTzPyhKPs8PWq07tb",\n\t"id": 3,\n\t",\n\t"order_details": [{"meal_id": 1, "quantity": 3}, {"meal_id": 2, "quantity": 2}]\n}'`

I am using Postman to post the data.

I want to store the access token into some variable like so:

```
access_token = request.POST.get("access_token")
```

with the post data

I am still fairly new to Django, any help would be great.

Comment: Django doesn't know that you're posting JSON or any other format. You need to decode the data you get. Google up `json.loads`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just doing a json.loads should work.

```
import json

json_data = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: body needs to be decoded.
otherwise you get
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Answer (score 4):

Request.POST gets populated when you are sending form data.
see [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) for details.
Since, in your case, you are posting 'plain' json, you will find your payload under request.body.
You can decode the body from binary to a dict as follows:

```
import json

body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
access_token = body.get("access_token")
```

Comment: some explanation why this answer is an improvement over the other answers will help it.

Answer (score -1):

you need to decode the json first:

```
import json
variable = urlopen(request).read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(variable)
```

then you can retrive your informations

```
for i in json_obj:
   token = i['access_token']
   order_details = i['order_details']
```

Hope this help

Comment: This isn't relevant to this use case, which is a backend endpoint receiving a POST request.